# Batch Request support in WebAPI service

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have registered the Batch WebAPI and WebAPI service as follows in webapiconfig.cs

```
config.Routes.MapHttpBatchRoute(
                routeName: "WebApiBatch",
                routeTemplate: "api/$batch",
                batchHandler: new DefaultHttpBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer));

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

And webAPI service as follows

Employee Class

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public Employee()
        {

        }
        public Employee(int id, string LN, string FN)
        {
            this.EmployeeID = id;
            this.LastName = LN;
            this.FirstName = FN;

        }
    }
```

Employee Interface

```
interface IEmployeeRepository
    {
        IEnumerable<Employee> GetAll();
        Employee Get(int EmployeeID);
        Employee Add(Employee emp);
        void Remove(int EmployeeID);
        bool Update(Employee emp);
    }
```

Employee Repository

```
public class EmployeeRepository : IEmployeeRepository
    {
        private List<Employee> emp = new List<Employee>();

        public EmployeeRepository()
        {
            emp.Add(new Employee(1, "Davolio", "Nancy"));
            emp.Add(new Employee(2, "Fuller", "Andrew"));
            emp.Add(new Employee(3, "Leverling", "Janet"));
            emp.Add(new Employee(4, "Peacock", "Margaret"));
            emp.Add(new Employee(5, "Buchanan", "Steven"));
        }

        public IEnumerable<Employee> GetAll()
        {
            return emp;
        }

        public Employee Get(int id)
        {
            return emp.Find(p => p.EmployeeID == id);
        }

        public Employee Add(Employee eObj)
        {
            if (eObj == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("eObj");
            }
            emp.Add(eObj);
            return eObj;
        }

        public void Remove(int id)
        {
            emp.RemoveAll(p => p.EmployeeID == id);
        }

        public bool Update(Employee eObj)
        {
            if (eObj == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("eObj");
            }
            int index = emp.FindIndex(p => p.EmployeeID == eObj.EmployeeID);
            if (index == -1)
            {
                return false;
            }
            emp.RemoveAt(index);
            emp.Add(eObj);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

WebAPI controller

```
public class EmployeeController : ApiController
    {
        static readonly IEmployeeRepository repository = new EmployeeRepository();
        // GET api/<controller>
        [HttpGet]
        public object Get()
        {


            var queryString = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString;
            var data = repository.GetAll().ToList();
            return new { Items = data, Count = data.Count() };
        }

        public Employee GetEmployee(int id)
        {
            Employee emp = repository.Get(id);
            if (emp == null)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
            return emp;
        }

        // POST api/<controller>
        public HttpResponseMessage PostEmployee(Employee emp)
        {
            emp = repository.Add(emp);
            var response = Request.CreateResponse<Employee>(HttpStatusCode.Created, emp);

            string uri = Url.Link("Employee", new { id = emp.EmployeeID });
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
            return response;
        }
         [HttpPut]
        // PUT api/<controller>
        public void PutEmployee(Employee emp)
        {
            if (!repository.Update(emp))
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }

        }
        [HttpDelete]
         public void Delete(int id)
        {
          //  int empID = int32
            Employee emp = repository.Get(id);
            if (emp == null)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }

            repository.Remove(id);
        }
    }
```

I have raised the ajax request from the client, in order to access the service as follows
I have set the batch request in data field of ajax

```
--batch_ec79f662-862e-4016-a19a-1dbff86d7120
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changeset_eb327bfc-5424-47b6-becf-416c43e13899

--changeset_eb327bfc-5424-47b6-becf-416c43e13899
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary 

POST /api/Employee HTTP/1.1
Content-Id: 0
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 

{"EmployeeID":6,"FirstName":"angel","LastName":"dsfs"}

--changeset_eb327bfc-5424-47b6-becf-416c43e13899
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary 

PUT /api/Employee HTTP/1.1
Content-Id: 1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 

{"EmployeeID":2,"FirstName":"kalai","LastName":"selvi"}


--changeset_eb327bfc-5424-47b6-becf-416c43e13899
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary 

PUT /api/Employee HTTP/1.1
Content-Id: 2
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 

{"EmployeeID":3,"FirstName":"Janet","LastName":"Leverling"}


--changeset_eb327bfc-5424-47b6-becf-416c43e13899
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary 

DELETE /api/Employee(3) HTTP/1.1
Content-Id: 3
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 

--changeset_eb327bfc-5424-47b6-becf-416c43e13899--
--batch_ec79f662-862e-4016-a19a-1dbff86d7120--
```

And the entire ajax request

```
$.ajax{
Content-type: "multipart/mixed; charset=UTF-8;boundary=batch_ec79f662-862e-4016-a19a-1dbff86d7120",
data:"--batch_ec79f662-862e-4016-a19a-1dbff86d7120↵Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changeset_eb327bfc-5424-47b6-becf-416c43e13899↵↵--changeset_eb327bfc-5424-47b6-becf-416c43e13899↵Content-Type: application/http↵Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ↵↵POST /api/Employee HTTP/1.1↵Content-Id: 0↵Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 ↵↵{"EmployeeID":6,"FirstName":"angel","LastName":"dsfs"}↵↵--changeset_eb327bfc-5424-47b6-becf-416c43e13899↵Content-Type: application/http↵Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ↵↵PUT /api/Employee HTTP/1.1↵Content-Id: 1↵Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 ↵↵{"EmployeeID":2,"FirstName":"kalai","LastName":"selvi"}↵↵↵--changeset_eb327bfc-5424-47b6-becf-416c43e13899↵Content-Type: application/http↵Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ↵↵PUT /api/Employee HTTP/1.1↵Content-Id: 2↵Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 ↵↵{"EmployeeID":3,"FirstName":"Janet","LastName":"Leverling"}↵↵↵--changeset_eb327bfc-5424-47b6-becf-416c43e13899↵Content-Type: application/http↵Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ↵↵DELETE /api/Employee(3) HTTP/1.1↵Content-Id: 3↵Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 ↵↵--changeset_eb327bfc-5424-47b6-becf-416c43e13899--↵--batch_ec79f662-862e-4016-a19a-1dbff86d7120--",
type:"POST",
url:"/api/Employee"
}
```

After raise the request, I got an exception message

```
1.  {Message: "The request entity's media type 'multipart/mixed' is not supported for this resource.",…}
1.  ExceptionMessage:"No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Employee' from content with media type 'multipart/mixed'."
2.  ExceptionType:"System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException"
3.  Message:"The request entity's media type 'multipart/mixed' is not supported for this resource."
StackTrace:"   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
↵   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync(HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
↵   at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"
```

Where did i commit the mistake

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are calling the actual batch route that you configured and not an endpoint on the EmployeeController directly. When you do that (I see your ajax call has url:"/api/Employee") then you will get that message since those endpoints don't support mixed mode. If you call the batch route instead (/api/batch), then that should do the trick. The endpoint I used didn't have the dollar sign in it however, I configured it to just be api/batch:

```
                routeName: "batch",
            routeTemplate: "api/batch",
```